# ZendFramework echo db values if first string = a?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have this code at the moment to echo out all my database entries, I am wondering what it looks like in ZF to echo out the entries if the first value of the db entry is a.

Code:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($this->clubs as $clubs) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'club-description', 'action' => 'index', 'club_id' => $clubs->id));?>">
        <?php echo $this->escape($clubs->club_name);?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($clubs->rating);?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Thanks

Rik

Comment: So you just want to show the clubs whose name starts with 'A'? As if so, this is something you'd do in your database query, rather than loading all the data out and then filtering it.

Comment: I will end up having all of them the reason i want to filter them is I want to have all the items beginning with a under the header "a" then the same for "b" and "c" etc.. so you see eventually I will have all the items listed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on your comment it sounds like you want to group the clubs by letter on the page. Assuming they are being ordered alphabetically in your database query, the simplest way to do this is to keep a variable which stores the first letter of the last club in the loop. Then, on each iteration, you compare the first letter of the current club with the first letter of the previous club. If they are different, you output a new heading.

With your code this would look something like this:

```
<?php
$previousLetter = false;
?>
<table>
<?php foreach($this->clubs as $clubs) : ?>
    <?php
    $firstLetter = substr($clubs->_club_name, 0, 1);
    if ($firstLetter != $previousLetter) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $firstLetter; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'club-description', 'action' => 'index', 'club_id' => $clubs->id));?>">
        <?php echo $this->escape($clubs->club_name);?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($clubs->rating);?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $previousLetter = $firstLetter; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, next task is to format the HTML so it isn't in a table :D Thanks for the help!